# Getting index error in the code in python

Tags: python

```
def fact(n):
    fac = 1
    while (n>1):
        fac = fac*n
        n -= 1

    return fac

z = 0
t = int(raw_input())
nz = []
for i in range(0,t):
    c = 0
    n = int(raw_input())
    z = fact(n)

    z = list(str(z))
    for j in range(len(z)-1,1,-1):
        if z[j] != '0':
            break
        else:
            c +=1
    nz[i].append(c)
for k in range(0,t):
    print nz[k]
```

Hello I am getting

> Indexerror : index out of range at " nz[i].append(c)

This program should calculate trailing zeros in the factorial of N.
Can you also please help me optimize my code, so it can run also for large values of N?

Comment: `nz` is an empty list. `nz[i]` is not valid for any `i`.

Comment: At what value of `i` does it error on you?

Comment: If you want to solve this problem quickly, you have to avoid calculating factorial. With right method you should be able to calculate number of trailing zeros of `1000!` by hand in a minute. Then generalize it to algorithmic solution.

Answer (score 6):

`nz` is empty list. It doesn't have any elements, so `nz[i]` would always raise `IndexError`. Perhaps you meant `nz.append(c)` ie. add `c` at the end of `nz`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how does [append()](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) work:

> list.append(x)
>
> Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

so you may want to change `nz[i].append(c)` to `nz.append(c)`, since your `i` index is already handled by the append function. You're actually assuming you have an `i` element in your list, which is false, since you are using an empty list

About optimizing, your problem is probably due to your recursion limit. Try `import sys; sys.getrecursionlimit()` in your python shell, you should see something like 1000 as result.

Swapping for an iterative version of the factorial function *could* be a start

```
def fact(n):
    r = 1
    for x in range (n):
        r = r * (x+1)
    return r
```

Comment: Also please state how to optimize the program so that it will give fast outputs for large inputs of the order of 10000000

Comment: Also please state how to optimize the program so that it will give fast outputs for large inputs of the order of 10000000 ???

also please state i used previously a recursive function or factorial, but it was giving error (an error was given to a given line no. where the return statement was there) for larger inputs of the order of 10^8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq please! You can edit your comments, no need for "spamming" them!

Comment: No not an interactive way , but rather an efficient algorithmic way to calculate factorials for very large no.s of the order of 10 ^8 or 10^9 ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751334/fast-algorithms-for-computing-the-factorial read the pdf here then :)