# calculating factorial of large numbers in 0.5 second with python

Tags: python, factorial

I've been trying to find a super fast code that can calculate the factorial of a big number like 70000 in 0.5 second,My own code could do it in 10 seconds.I've searched everywhere, every code I find has memory error problem or is not as fast as I want. Can anyone help me with this?

```
enter code here
import math
num =int(raw_input())
usefrm=0
if len(str(num)) > 2:
  if int(str(num)[-2]) % 2 == 0:
        usefrm = 'even'
  else:
        usefrm = 'odd'
else:
  if num % 2 == 0:
        usefrm = 'even1'
  else:
        usefrm = 'odd1'

def picknumber(num):
  s = str(math.factorial(num))
  l = []
  for n in s:
        if int(n) != 0:
              l.append(int(n))
  return l[-1]

  def picknumber1(num):
  s = str(num)
  l = []
  for n in s:
        if int(n) != 0:
              l.append(int(n))
  return l[-1]
  if usefrm == 'even':
     e=picknumber1(6*picknumber(int(num/5))*picknumber(int(str(num)[-1])))
  if usefrm == 'odd':
     e=picknumber1(4*picknumber(int(num/5))*picknumber(int(str(num)[-1]))) 
  else:
  e=picknumber1(math.factorial(num))
  print e
```

Comment: 70000! is absolutely gigantic. What kind of big number library are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751334/fast-algorithms-for-computing-the-factorial (just with the python flag)

Comment: Using the gmpy library I can calculate 70000! in around 0.5 seconds on this old 2GHz  machine.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to put my code.I just fixed it. @Bathsheba

Comment: What's the goal here, algorithmic or practical?  It takes me < 0.2 s to compute 70000! using the built-in `math.factorial`.

Comment: @DSM Wow! `math.factorial(70000)` takes over 43 seconds on this old beast; that includes printing it (to /dev/null).

Comment: That time measurement (using the bash time command) was on Python 3.6; on Python 2.6 it takes over 2m23s.

Comment: @PM2Ring `math.factorial(70000)` took 0.18 seconds on my system, timed using `timeit.timeit` (not including import times)

Comment: Shouldn't `reduce()` do it really fast?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: A significant proportion of my times are for the conversion / printing. If I just do the calculation, then the times (for `math.factorial(70000)`) are 1.312s on Py3.6 and 25.007s on Py2.6.

Comment: @Boris Not really; `reduce` is still doing the factorial arithmetic with Python integers, at Python speed.

Answer (score 1):

For most practical use, the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is very fast and quite accurate

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

def fact(n):
    d = Decimal(n)
    return (Decimal(2 * math.pi) * d).sqrt() * (d / Decimal(math.e)) ** d

print(fact(70000))

1.176811014417743803074731978E+308759
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the commutativity property of integer multiplication.

When multiplied numbers are long (they do not fit in a single word), the time necessary to perform the operation grows superlinearly with their length.

If you multiply the smallest (shortest in terms of memory representation) factors (and partial products) first, you may save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a perfect precision, you can use the Stirling's approximation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

```
import np
n! ~ np.sqrt(2*np.pi*n)*(n/np.e)**n
```

for large n values. This calculation is literally instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `math.factorial()`. For example:

```
from math import factorial 
factorial(7000)
```

with **execution time of 20.5 msec** for calculating the factorial of *7000*:

```
python -m timeit -c "from math import factorial; factorial(7000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 20.5 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to make use of threads.

Comment: Please make a more elaborate answer OP could actually use. Thank you.